# How to show that the set is at most countable?

Tags: real-analysis

$f(x)$ is a real-valued function on $\mathbb{R}$. How to show that the set $E=\{x\in\mathbb{R}: \lim_{y\to x}f(y)=+\infty\}$ is at most countable?

Comment: @Mathematician42 ? Let $g(x)\begin{cases}\cot^2 \pi x &\text{if defined}\\0&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$ and $f(x)=|1/x|+g(1/x)$ (with $f(0)$ arbitrary). Then $0\in E$ and $\pm1/n \in E$

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: Ah yes, said something too fast here. So $E$ can have limit points itself, that's annoying. Should have known that that argument sounded too easy!

Comment: Perhaps you could try a proof by contradiction. Suppose $E$ is uncountable, then there is an interval $(z,z+\varepsilon)$ such that $(z,z+\varepsilon)\cap E$ is uncountable. Hopefully this implies that $f$ basically has to be infinity somewhere, which is not allowed. But still the example above shows that you really would have to exploit the uncountable nature of $E$ to conclude something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$a\in E$ means that for every $M\in\Bbb N$, we can pick $u,v\in\Bbb Q$ with $u<a<v$ and $f(x)>M$ for all $x\in(u,v)\setminus\{a\}$.
Write $(u,v)=\phi(a,M)$.
We may assume wlog. that $\phi(a,M+1)\Subset \phi(a,M)$.

Start with $E_0:=E$ and assume $E_n$ is uncountable.
As $\phi(a,n)$ can take only countably many values, there exists $(u_n,v_n)$ such that $\phi(a,n)=(u_n,v_n)$ for uncountably many $a\in E_n$.
Let $E_{n+1}=\{\,a\in E_n\mid \phi(a,n)=(u_n,v_n)\,\}$ and recurese.

This gives us a nested sequence of uncountable sets $E_n$, accompanied by a sequence of nested intervals $(u_1,v_1)\Supset (u_2,v_2)\Supset\ldots$.
Pick $\alpha\in\bigcap(a_n,v_n)$ and let $M=\lceil f(\alpha)\rceil$.
Then for  $a\in E_M$, we have $f(x)>M$ for all $x\in (u_M,v_M)\setminus\{a\}$. As $\alpha\in(u_M,v_M)$, this means $\alpha=a$, contradicting $|E_M|>1$.